# Incorrect Z Value in Slope and hillshade Raster from QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope, hillshade

I have to create a TIFF for hillshade and Slope from data obtained by Eiva software, basically a XYZ file. When I drop in the XYZ or TIFF exported from Eiva and try to create the layers they seem ok but when I drop back into Eiva the Z values have changed quite drastically, like 90m. It is not just a case of the Z value being opposite values in Eiva as this wouldn’t match.

Comment: No meters think it has been explained to me that it is not supposed to be real world Z but Z as a incline of slope.